# Retain/Release through intermediary method

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

I think I understand retain/release in objective-C for the most part.  However, I have a specific case I am unsure about.  Here is an example:

```
+ (NSString *)getPlayerNameByIndex:(NSInteger)globalIndex:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
{
    ...
    Player *player = [PlayerHelper loadPlayer:globalIndex];
    NSString *name = [PlayerHelper getPlayerName:player :addressBook];
    [player release];

    // 'retain' here?    
    return name;
}

+ (NSString *)getPlayerName:(Player *)player:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBook
{
    ...
    NSString *name = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:player.nickname] autorelease];
    return name;
}
```

So then I call...

```
NSString *name = [PlayerHelper getPlayerNameByIndex:index:addressBook];
// name is 'autorelease'?
```

What I saw on random occasions is that the view sometimes shows the 'name' field as empty when it populates the table after coming back from another view. This could be another issue but I want to be sure of my use of 'autorelease'.

The core of my question is the use of 'autorelease' in getPlayerName.  Does the 'autorelease' state of being get passed through method getPlayerNameByIndex to the caller?

Or, do I have to call 'retain' in the intermediary method?  I am thinking 'autorelease' may be releasing in method getPlayerNameByIndex.

Hopefully my question is clear.  Any help is appreciated.

Update: Some more info for clarification...

```
NSError *error = nil;
Player *player = nil;
NSArray *array = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if ([array count] == 1)
{
    player = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    [player retain];
}
```

This is essentially the "loadPlayer" method which loads info from core data.  From the answers it sounds like I do not need to call [player retain], since it is an autorelated object, and I can simply return "player" and use it?  Thanks for the responses!

Comment: the static analyzer is there to help you!

Comment: I will check that out pronto Justin.. thanks!

Comment: The static analyzer is gorgeous!  I don't know why I haven't used it.  I do use the leak checker.  Working on this.

Comment: yeah, it can quickly point out a lot of issues a compiler may miss, and save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The core of my question is the use of 'autorelease' in getPlayerName. Does the 'autorelease' state of being get passed through method getPlayerNameByIndex to the caller?

The answer is yes.

> Or, do I have to call 'retain' in the intermediary method?

whether you want to call `retain` depends on the semantics of your method.

In Obj-C/Cocoa, the following convention applies: a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” will return a `retained` object; otherwise you can expect to get an `autoreleased` object, then it is the caller responsibility to retain it according to its needs.

> I am thinking 'autorelease' may be releasing in method getPlayerNameByIndex.

autoreleased objects are released at the next point in time when the autorelease pool is drained; this is usually associated to going back to the main loop (though, no details are available about this); so you can be pretty sure that auto-releasing does not kick in in `getPlayerNameByIndex`...

Hope this helps clarifying the issue...

Comment: The returned object may or may not be autoreleased; it's simply not owned by the caller. It could still be owned by another object. Ownership and being in an autorelease pool are not the same thing.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: have I used the word "ownership" in my answer? I am missing something... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your sentence "...otherwise you can expect to get an `autorelease`d object", which is not quite accurate in that the object's membership in an autorelease pool is both unknown and, I believe, the wrong thing to be thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

In `getPlayerNameByIndex` The line:

```
[player release];
```

is wong, remove it.  You did not obtain ownership.  Ownership is ob gained by calling a method with alloc or the method names starts with new, copy or an explicit retain. (NARC).

You do not need to release player because you did not obtain ownership, see above rule.

In `getPlayerName:`
can be simplified to:

```
return player.nickname;
```

The method name can be simplifies to:

```
+ (NSString *)getPlayerName:(Player *)player
```

Comment: Not what he was asking, I think, but good spot! To the originating poster: see sergio's description of the new/alloc/copy rule; the factory method you used to get player wasn't new, alloc or copy so you don't own that reference.